# Quickly Glade Button link to external program

Tags: application-development, gtk, glade

this is my first post so forgive me for any errors. I am using Quickly to create a program. The problem I am having, is when I create the button, I am unable to set the command I wish to launch on the click activation. I have looked around for tips on using the subprocess module, but I could not find anything helpful. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: [Solved]. The problem was that I didn't "import os" into the script, and I didn't know about "os.system(programname)"

Answer (score 3):

The OP solved the problem(see above comment) by `import os`, in which case `os.system(program)` may be used.